# KeyErrorr:'to_user_name

Tags: python, twitter

Has anyone come across the ['KeyErrorr:'to_user_name''] as in below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finalised1.py", line 53, in <module>
    touser = tweet['to_user_name']
KeyError: 'to_user_name'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_user_name` is not a key in the `tweet` dictionary.

Comment: If you are still here, I would like to thank you for answering my first python question 7 years ago. :)

Comment: My pleasure! I hope you're still enjoying python!